# Error installing apc for php on linux/centos

Tags: php, apc

I followed this tutorial http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/how-to-install-apc-alternative-php-cache-on-centos-5-6/ to install apc on my centos vps hosting but I get some error messages on the last step. Here is the complete log from the terminal:

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/include -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/main -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c -o apc.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/include -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/main -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:393: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_compile_array':
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_match_array':
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
[root@lvps178-77-79-75 APC-3.1.9]# make install
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/include -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/main -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c -o apc.lo
 cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/include -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/main -I/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:393: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_compile_array':
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_match_array':
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/usr/local/src/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how you solved this issue , can you please share ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found this to work on CentOS 6.2:

```
sudo yum install php-pear
sudo yum install php-devel
sudo yum install httpd-devel
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install pcre-devel
sudo pecl install apc-beta
```

Complete post here: http://www.accella.net/installing-apc-on-centos-5/

Answer (score 19):

USE:

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev

yum install pcre-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) installed ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using remi repository. (CentOS release 6.5, PHP 5.4)
You can list the packages available by following command

```
yum --enablerepo=remi list php54*
yum --enablerepo=remi list php54* | grep apc
```

I got following apc package

```
php54-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64     4.0.7-1.el6.remi         @remi
```

Now you can use following command to install apc

```
yum install php54-php-pecl-apcu --enablerepo=remi
```